# What is the name of this "spinner like" control?

Tags: android, android-widget

Does anyone know the name of this "Language Select" control? Its not a spinner.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out it was a [NumberPicker](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/NumberPicker.html) control.

```
NumberPicker transportProviderPicker = (NumberPicker) findViewById(R.id.pkr_transport_provider);
transportProviderPicker.setValue(0);
transportProviderPicker.setMaxValue(0);
transportProviderPicker.setDisplayedValues(transportProviders);
```

Answer (score 2):

This is the custom view. You can download the library from https://github.com/ai212983/android-spinnerwheel and modify it as per your requirement.